# How to get all connections between pixels in an image

Tags: python, image, pixel, a-star

Developing the A* algorithm for path planning, I am trying to get a list called *edges* in which all connections from one pixel to its neighbour pixels that occur in a non-occupied space (where the pixel value is 1).

The image from which I compute this connections is a 351x335 pixels image.

Pixels P2,4,6,8 are at a distance=1 from the center, while pixels P1,3,5,7 are at a approximate distance=1.4 from the center (Pythagoras theorem); see image:

[image: Neighbourhood of a pixel]

The code written for the edges loop is never ending. Is this taking too much computational time due to the loops? The *vertices* loop ends in a second or so.

Note: I am initializing the lists as two very big arrays and cutting them at the end to not use dynamic allocation.

**EDIT:** The image (imOut) is the following one:
[Link to image used as map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJeoh.png)

**EDIT:** The full code is the following:

```
'''
IMPORTS
'''

import cv2 as cv  # Import OpenCV
import numpy as np  # Import Numpy
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import math
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import arange


'''
CODE SETTINGS
'''
# Allowing to print full array without truncation
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)

'''
MAIN PROGRAM
'''
im = rgb2gray(cv.imread('map1.png'))
imOut = im  # Making a copy of the image to output
# plt.imshow(imOut)
# plt.show()



vertices = np.zeros((imOut.shape[0]*imOut.shape[1], 3))  # 1st col to x, 2nd col to y, 3rd col to heuristic (euclidean distance to QGoal)
edges = np.zeros((100*imOut.shape[0]*imOut.shape[1], 3))     # 1st col 1st vertex, 2nd col 2nd vertex, 3rd col edge length
# Initialization of vertices with start pos.


# CREATE VERTICES AND EDGES LISTS FROM THE MAP PROVIDED

'''
Vertices List -> Add all obstacle-free configurations to the vertices list.
Edges List -> Go pixel by pixel in the map and, if they are obstacle-free configurations,
add, out of the 8 neighbouring pixels, the ones that are obstacle-free as feasible edges.
'''

# Vertices list creation
indexVertices = 0
for i in range(0, imOut.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0, imOut.shape[1]):
        if imOut[i,j] == 1:     # If it's in free space
            # Compute heuristic to goal node (euclidean distance).
            heuristic = math.sqrt(pow(i-QGoal[0],2) 
                                + pow(j-QGoal[1],2))
            vertices[indexVertices,:] = [i, j, heuristic]
            indexVertices = indexVertices + 1

vertices = vertices[0:indexVertices,:]

# Edges list creation
# I loop over the same vertices array, as it only contains the free pixels.
indexEdges = 0
for i in range(0, vertices.shape[0]):
    for k in range(0, vertices.shape[0]):
        # If it is not the same pixel that we are checking
        if i != k:
            # Check if it is a neighbouring pixel and, if so, 
            #add it to the list of edges with its distance(path cost).
            pathCost = (math.sqrt(pow(vertices[i,0] 
                                    - vertices[k,0], 2) 
                                + pow(vertices[i,1] 
                                    - vertices[k,1], 2))
            if pathCost == 1 or round(pathCost,1) == 1.4:
                edges[indexEdges,:] = [i, k, pathCost]
                indexEdges = indexEdges + 1

edges = edges[0:indexEdges,:]
```

Comment: Please include a bit more code so your sample can be run. Several variables, including `imOut`, `vertices`, and `QGoal` are not defined anywhere. Also, please include a sample image that we can test with. Also, just to clarify, do you believe your code is actually an infinite loop or is it just taking too long to run?

Comment: @supersam654 I would say it takes too long to run, and I would say that it is caused by the euclidean distance computation that I am performing with math.sqrt() combined with pow().

I added what you asked for. Now you should be able to run the code.